# Beautiful Soup - how to get href

Tags: beautifulsoup

I can't seem to be able to extract the href (there is only one `<strong>Website:</strong>` on the page) from the following soup of html:

```
<div id='id_Website'>
<strong>Website:</strong> 
<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>www.google.com</a>
</div></div><div>
```

This is what I thought should work

```
href = soup.find("strong" ,text=re.compile(r'Website')).next["href"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.next` in this case is a `NavigableString` containing the whitespace between the `<strong>` tag and the `<a>` tag.  Also, the `text=` attribute is for matching `NavigableString`s, rather than elements.

The following does what you want, I think:

```
import re
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

html = '''<div id='id_Website'>
<strong>Website:</strong> 
<a href='http://google.com' target='_blank' rel='nofollow'>www.google.com</a>
</div></div><div>'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for t in soup.findAll(text=re.compile(r'Website:')):
    # Find the parent of the NavigableString, and see
    # whether that's a <strong>:
    s = t.parent
    if s.name == 'strong':
        print s.nextSibling.nextSibling['href']
```

... but that isn't very robust.  If the enclosing `div` has a predictable ID, then it would better to find that, and then find the first `<a>` element within it.

Comment: This does what I want. Thank you. How can I search by ID to get the next href value?

Comment: You could use something like `soup.findAll('div', id=re.compile('Website$'))` to get all the `div`s to consider - without seeing other examples, it's not clear how you would pick them out, though.